# Prime gap as a power of log

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let for  $ 0\le\alpha\le 1 $ the quantity  $ I_{\alpha}(x) : =\dfrac{\sharp\{n\le x,\log^{1-\alpha}n\le p_{n+1}-p_{n}\le\log^{1+\alpha}n\}}{\pi(x)} $ and  $ J(\alpha)=\lim_{x\to\infty}I_{\alpha}(x) $.

Under Cramer's conjecture one has  $J(1)=1 $ .

Is there a heuristics giving the value of  $ \alpha_{0} $ such that  $J(\alpha_{0})=1/2 $?

Comment: Let $X$ a sequence of **independent** random variables : $X(n) = 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{\log n}, X(n) = 0$ otherwise. Let $\Pi(k) = \sum_{n \le k} X(n)$ and $Q$ the random sequence such that $\Pi(Q(k)) = k$. What is the [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for the random variable $Q(k+1)-Q(k)$ ?

Comment: Allo.. What is $\mathbb{P}[Q(k+1)-Q(k) = m]$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conjecturally, the distribution of prime gaps (let's say we first divide them by $2$ since they are essentially all even) follows an approximate geometric distribution with scale $\lambda^{-1} = \log n$.

Thus I would expect the halfway point to occur in an interval of the form $ \alpha \log n \le p_{n+1} - p_n \le \beta \log n$, rather than a polylog law. In other words, we should expect $\lim_{x \to 0^+} J(x) = 1$, but $J(0) = 0$.  It is likely that no such $\alpha_0$ exists.

Cramér's conjecture concerns the extreme values of the prime gap function: it does not predict that they occur with any regularity.

Comment: The equivalent model I mentioned above gives an approximate geometric distribution of parameter $p_n =\frac{1}{\log (n\log n)} \sim \frac1{\log n}$ whose mean is $\mu_n = \log n$ and [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) $\sigma_n =(1-p_n)^{1/2} \log n$. So we may expect under this model a positive proportion of prime gaps to be within $\mu_n \pm \epsilon \sigma_n$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, that sounds pretty reasonable.